# Choose where to save Catalina screenshot individually

Tags: macos, catalina, filesystem, screen-capture

Should be a simple question: When I take a screenshot, I would like to be able to choose which folder on my hard drive it can go into, the way I can with every single other program (and could in the past with Grab and Jing). But with the Catalina screenshot tool, I cannot find an option to do this. There's a way to change the *default* folder to save screenshots (so that it doesn't clutter up my desktop by default - thank goodness!), but I can't find any place to choose where to save each individual screenshot when its created, short of pressing Move to Finder and manually moving it myself. Is there some way of choosing the save location that I haven't been able to find yet? Or do I have to change the default location every time, and remember to do that *before* I hit capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - after invoking <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>, you will see the small dialog with choices for "entire screen", "window", etc, you will also see a choice for "Options". Click that to get a pop-up selection item - that's where you'll find your individual choices for file location.

Comment: Hm, OK. I thought that was just to change the default directory, but yeah, I guess you can use it to save it individually. It's weird and unintuitive to always have to change the location *before* you hit save, but I guess it'll do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @DisplacedHoser: There are other options you can change (default location, file type, etc), but you'll likely have to do that from the command line [REF1](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-change-where-screenshots-are-saved-on-mac), [REF2](https://www.techjunkie.com/how-to-customize-screenshot-options-in-mac-os-x/). I **wish** I knew how to re-write **all** of the `Save To...` default options... I've long suspected there must be a way, but I've never been able to find it.